# Comparing str.erase() efficiency in C++

Tags: c++, string, performance, erase

Suppose a string contains many leading whitespace characters. My task is to remove those characters.

I am thinking of this:

```
while(1) {
    if(str[i] == ' ')
        str.erase(str.begin()+i);
    else
        break;
}
```

Will it be O(1) per operation or more than O(n)? I read in many blogs that we should not erase a single element because the whole string might get copied to another place to maintain continuous memory allocation.

Then what about this kind of erase:

```
while(1) {
    if(str[i] == ' '){
        cnt++;
        break; 
    }
}
str.erase(0, cnt);
```

Which one is better?

Comment: Well, the first loop is infinite, so I sincerely hope you're *not* thinking that when you say your thinking that. There is no exit case.

Comment: Well, now the first one will invoke undefined behavior if the string is entirely spaces. Sooner or later you'll land on the `end` via `i` and the deref will invoke UB. The second stops on first space, so it will trim at most one character, not all leading.Before trying to decide which is better, start with something that *works*.

Comment: Why not simply include `cstring` and use `str.erase (0, strspn (str.c_str(), " \t"));`?

Comment: Or `str.erase(str.begin(), std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace));` after including `<cctype>`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: If you `#include <cstring>`, you have `std::strspn`.  For `::strspn` you must `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @BenVoigt -- strange, I must have a funny compiler. After including `cstring`, I have `strspn`, no `std` required.  `gcc (GCC) 8.3.0` ? (don't get me wrong, I see [std::strspn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strspn), but I also am compiling with no complaint, so I suspect it is included in the default namespace)

Comment: In fact it works as `strspn` or `std::strspn` -- so I'll let you gcc source gurus elaborate on that one -- I can't give a cogent answer for it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Any header can include any other header -- you might even get `strspn` from `#include <math.h>` -- but if you rely on that you've got non-portable code, not standard C++.

Comment: That is a good answer. I have `iostream` and `cstring`, so it is pulled from somewhere. Compliance, `std::strspn`. I would expect gcc to warn of the issue, but obviously it does not. (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - the basic idea is the <cheader> headers *must* declare their symbols in the `std` namespace, while the <header.h> headers *must* declare their symbols in the global namespace. However, each variant _may_ do the other behavior as well. So you might get lucky and find that `<cstring>` declares `strspan` but it's not guaranteed and I've certainly found modern compilers/runtimes where that's not the case. If you want to call it as `strspan`, just include `<string.h>` rather than `<cstring>.

Comment: Th people have started discussing here their own problems. what about my problem  which one is better and why?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Yes, thank you. I had never thought through it from a guaranteed availability standpoint when including the `cxxxx` headers. It makes perfect sense. But at least with gcc, when including the C-string functions I've never run into a circumstance where it was not already included in the global namespace -- now I'll have to go chase it down to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: @user11440659 - the short answer is calling `str.erase(str.begin()+i);` multiple times within a loop is going to be less efficient that deriving a count and calling `.erase()` once. Especially when erasing from the front of a string. I'll see if I can find a link to the recent article on the relative efficiencies of erasing from the front verses back of a container.

Comment: I believe this was the one [6 Tips to supercharge C++11 vector performance](https://www.acodersjourney.com/6-tips-supercharge-cpp-11-vector-performance/) applies to containers in general.

Comment: @WhozCraig "*Sooner or later you'll land on the `end` via `i` and the deref will invoke UB*" - not true since C++11, where `str[str.size()]` is well defined as returning a reference to a null char.

Answer (score 3):

The first example is rather inefficient. `erase` moves all of the elements beyond the point of the erase down to fill in the space that `erase` creates; this code ends up copying all the later elements of the string once **for each leading space**. The second example doesn't do what the question asks for, because that `break` statement exits the loop early. But the approach in the second one is much better. In general, if you're calling `erase` more than once you've probably made a mistake. It's much better to find the first character that you want to keep, and **then** remove all the ones in front of that. So:

```
std::string::size_type pos = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
if (pos != std::string::npos)
    str.erase(0, pos);
```

Comment: The first snippet does work (inefficiently), since the `break` is only reached once a non-space is found. And `erase(pos)` removes `[pos, end())` - I think you mean `erase(0, pos)`.

Comment: @aschepler `erase(pos)` removes character pointed by `pos`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

Comment: Yes, `erase(0, pos)`. Fixed.

Comment: @Criss It's the first overload, with default argument, since `pos` is a `size_type` and not an iterator.

Comment: ah, ok, sorry. I misunderstood pos to be an iterator

Answer (score -2):

Since you want to remove only **leading** white space chars, the best would be to perform binary-search-like algorithm to find first not-whitespace in O(log(N)). This, I believe, can be done with smart use of `std::upper_bound`. Then erase range `[0, result)` from the string.

Comment: That's why I said **smart** use.. You can define what "sorted" means, e.g. make all non-whitespace chars be equal to each other and greater than whitespace chars

Comment: "*You can define what "sorted" means, e.g. make all non-whitespace chars be equal to each other and greater than whitespace chars*" If all whitespace characters are less than all non-whitespace characters, you still have to *sort the string* so that all whitespace characters appear first. That's going to be slower than O(N), and it will also *break* the meaning of the string. The task is to remove leading whitespace, not *all whitespace*.